# How to use jQuery with Meteor framework

Tags: jquery, meteor

I am following discovermeteor.com tutorials, trying to do be creative and add my own stuff to it. One thing I want to do is to use jQuery to set a session value to be used as page title (not sure if that makes 100% sense though).

So I have been trying to trigger a session.set on document ready when some condition is met, but it doesn't seem to work.

my code example:

```
Template.layout.helpers({
    pageTitle: function() { return Session.get('pageTitle'); }
})

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    if ( $('section#main').hasClass('postlist')) {
        Session.set('pageTitle', 'Posts list');
    };
});
```

So, my question is, how do I work with jQuery and Meteor? Can I use jQuery just the way I am used to, or is there anything special I should be aware of? Many thanks

Comment: why are you taking a `$` as parameter in loal scope, it must be `event` that's why it's not working.

Answer (score 3):

In Meteor we don't use $(document).ready, instead you should use Meteor.startup which is equivalent :

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
    if ( $('section#main').hasClass('postlist')) {
        Session.set('pageTitle', 'Posts list');
    };
});
```

Comment: The `$` in OP's code refers to jQuery. It's not an _event_.

Comment: @undefined but when you will take a parameter as `$` in function, the global jquery's `$` will be replaced by parameter. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: That's not correct. `$`(_or any other name for the first parameter_) in the ready handler is a local variable, it overrides the global `$` only _in that context_,  it's used for avoiding conflicts with other libraries that use `$`. It's `noConflict` method that detaches the `$` from `window` object. http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: @undefined thanx for the comment, I didn't know that my answer is updated by saimeunt,

Comment: It seems (_unfortunately_) the edit and the comments confused the OP and he asked another question.